# Error building monero-stratum on macOS

Tags: macos, build, monero-stratum

I am getting an error building monero-stratum on macOS. `cmake` completes without error, but when I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
mac:monero-stratum powerkey$ make
Scanning dependencies of target cnutil
[ 20%] Building CXX object cnutil/CMakeFiles/cnutil.dir/src/cnutil.cpp.o
../monero-stratum/cnutil/src/cnutil.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.h' file not found
#include "cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [cnutil/CMakeFiles/cnutil.dir/src/cnutil.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [cnutil/CMakeFiles/cnutil.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am following the instructions [here](https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum/blob/master/README.md). Monero 12.2 is installed and working.

I am using MacPorts instead of homebrew on macOS High Sierra (10.13.5) and Xcode 9.4.1 is installed if that changes anything.

Comment: Did you run `MONERO_DIR=/path/to/monero cmake .` before make? Reason I ask is the build is not finding monero source code.

Comment: I did, and there are no errors or warnings. However, when I read your comment, I realized that my '/path/to/monero' was pointing to binaries, not source. That fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post that comment as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1):

My '/path/to/monero' was not correct. I was, incorrectly, pointing to monero binaries instead of source. Changing the path, to point to source corrects the problem.